# Why does my .htaccess file cause an internal error to some files when adding a slash?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file causes an internal error when I add a slash to a php file in the folder that the .htaccess file is in. Why does this happen and how could I prevent this error from happening?

**I would like the page where the internal error is being caused to display the php file (instead of a redirect as some users have the php file with a / at the end cached)**

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /content/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /content/errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /content/errors/500.php
```

Examples:

`https://mywebsite.com/folder/file` ✔️ works!

`https://mywebsite.com/folder/file.php` ✔️ works!

`https://mywebsite.com/folder/file/` ❌ 500 internal error

Comment: Apache views `file/` as a directory request. Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to include it in the rewrite

Comment: @Phil thanks for your comment! Very much appreciated, BUT adding  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` still did not fix my problem, the 500 internal error still persists.

Comment: Ah right, you'd need some way to capture the request filename prior to the trailing `/` to check for the existing `.php` file. I'm sure this has come up before, will do a bit of a search

Comment: How would I do so? I'm not that familiar with .htaccess

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417551/283366). They first rewrite requests for non-existent directories to the same URL, minus the trailing slash. From there, your existing rules should work

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36340272/283366) might also help

Comment: @Phil the last answer you linked me to worked flawlessly! Thank you! Also could you post this as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Comment: Give credit to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340231/283366) and answer that helped 